# new USB stick: backup GPT table corrupt, primary appears OK

Tags: mount, usb, gpt

Kubuntu - I can't mount/partition a new USB-stick

[1]
The
`sudo fdisk -l`
output is:

```
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 61 TiB, 67108864000000 bytes, 16384000000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 204B6E25-DFG5-5679-B8E8-8657TRTT85C
```

[2]
With `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb/`

I get this result:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

```
Problem opening /deb/sdb/ for reading! Error is 2.
The specified file does not exist!
```

[3]
`sudo sgdisk -e /dev/sdb`
shows up with

```
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! Error 5 reading partition table for CRC check!
Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
The operation has completed successfully.
```

[4]
What do I have to do to fix the GPT issue and successfully mount the USB stick?

Comment: seems like a faulty stick / detected with wrong size, 61TB (16384 million sectors) doesn't make too much sense. as for 2) you got a trailing /

Comment: Tthe usb-stick was sold as 64TB. so 61 TiB makes sense to me,

Comment: How many thousands of dollars did you pay for it?